# sequelize gancho beforeUpdate no funciona

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, sequelize.js, sequelize

Tengo un modelo de usuario sencillo con 2 hooks.

```
Usuario.beforeCreate(establecerSaltYPass)
Usuario.beforeUpdate(establecerSaltYPass)
```

el primero funciona perfectamente pero el beforeUpdate no se ejecuta, segun la documentacion no debería tener problema ejecutando lo siguiente

```
await Usuario.update(usuario, {
            where: {
                id
            }

        })
```

esta guardando la clave como texto plano, no sucede por ejemplo con el crear.
curiosamente beforeBulkUpdate si se ejecuta cuando se actualiza, este es el callback, el detalle es que en el bulk no tengo la propiedad changed o por lo menos no se como acceder.

```
const establecerSaltYPass = usuario => {
  if (usuario.changed('pass')) {
    usuario.salt = Usuario.generarSalt()
    usuario.pass = Usuario.encriptarPass(usuario.pass(), usuario.salt())
  }
}
```

hace su trabajo, lo que no se ejecuta es el gancho.

Answer (score 0):

Se que seguro ya se encontro solucion pero esto me sirvio a mi

```
await User.update(user, {
  where: {
    id
  },
  individualHooks: true,
});
```

individualHooks:true activa y hace funcionar el hook beforeUpdate

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).